# How to put a listing bloc and an image side-by-side?

Tags: floats, listings, positioning

for the finetuning I have to show a codelisting and the result as an image next to each other, otherwise it will be displayed on the next page and i have to crop it extremely.

Here's my progress so far:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b,caption={Alle HTML Überschriften (Quellcode)},label=lst:headings]
<h1>Überschrift erster Ordnung</h1>
<h2>Überschrift zweiter Ordnung</h2>
<h3>Überschrift dritter Ordnung</h3>
<h4>Überschrift vierter Ordnung</h4>
<h5>Überschrift fünfter Ordnung</h5>
<h6>Überschrift sechster Ordnung</h6>
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[height = 100px]{headings1}
\caption{Alle HTML Überschriften (Ansicht) \label{headingsimage}}
\end{figure}
```

How can I put them next to each other?

Comment: @SAM This ought NOT to be closed as a duplicate unless the OP here is using `memoir`. The answer there uses `\subbottom`. How should the OP define that in order to use the answer with a different class?

Comment: We need a complete minimal working example, please. As you can see, posting mere fragments leaves your question ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i propose a solution using `\minipage`, the code may looks ugly if several lines are too long and will get wraped, so you must choose good parameters of both `minipage` width (consider the space between the two blocs; dont use 100% of the line width), image scaling `scale` and `linewidth` to obtain a nice shape. i hope i answreed your question.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}  %listing bloc will have 50% of the line width 
\lstset{linewidth = 4cm, breaklines=true} %set your listing lines widths, and set breaklines to true
\begin{lstlisting}
Your code here here..........
Your code here here..........
Your code here here..........
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\qquad %space between listing bloc and the figure
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} %figure will have the remaning 40% of the line width
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image}  %the image must be resized or scaled if needed
\caption{caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it with minipage, too but got compiling errors, I accidently closed the figure to early